# Angular Material Table Generic Table Component Stopped Working in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I have a datatable component which provides a datatable layout which extends upon Material Table by abstracting away a lot of the boilerplate required to do filtering, pagination, sorting, and so on.  It provides Inputs on the datatable component to toggle those things and the data is provided using a datatable-column component which automatically creates the header and data definition for the column and uses ngTemplateOutlet for data projection to allow the datatable-column component to be interacted with simlarly to mat-cell.

In Angular 7.2 this worked perfectly, but when I recently upgraded to 8.2, this suddenly stopped working and I can't quite figure out why.

In the Chrome console it says "Cannot read property 'template' of undefined" and in Firefox is says "TypeError: column.headerCell is undefined"

It seems to be related to the directive being used to map contents in a datatable-column to a template for projection and something that must have changed between Angular 7 and 8 in regards to how that works.

Please see the code at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqezab

Thank you in advance for any insight or assistance you can provide.